# Issues setting up Percona Xtradb Cluster with 2 servers

Tags: cluster-computing, percona, xtradb

I'm trying to set up a Percona XtraDB cluster on two machines.. but i'm having a terrible time in getting the second machine up and running.

I have used [this article](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2012/08/29/setup-galera-with-sst-xtrabackup-method/) as a reference, and while it seems to be almost working, there's probably something basic i'm missing.

Machines are as follows:

```
Node 1: 192.168.2.10
Node 2: 192.168.2.11
```

Both machines run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The config file on Node 1 is similar to the article.

When i start this node using the above configuration, it works normally. I can log into it via command line and run the

```
mysql> SHOW status LIKE 'wsrep%';
```

command as it describes. Everything looks normal.

NOTE: Node 1 was previously a standard mySQL server, and has data already in the /var/lib/mysql folder. This has not affected it starting normally with the above configuration.

I then follow the steps outlined in the [article](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2012/08/29/setup-galera-with-sst-xtrabackup-method/) regarding adding a new node. This seems to be where I run into issues.

I created the my.ini on Node 2 **(192.168.2.11)**, and used a configuration similar to the article.

When I try starting the service using **service mysql start**, it says it's started, yet I can no longer connect via the command line.

I tried changing the config file on Node 1 back to the original one, and then starting Node 2, but thats not working either.

I have captured the logs by simply starting mysql with the mysqld command on the command line, and here's the trimmed result (only stuff with errors):

```
130206 14:53:56 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read 'ready <addr>' from: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup --role 'joiner' --address 'ip_address' --auth 'root:password' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --parent '14762'
        Read: '(null)'
130206 14:53:56 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup --role 'joiner' --address 'ip_address' --auth 'root:password' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' --parent '14762': 2 (No such file or directory)
130206 14:53:56 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to prepare for 'xtrabackup' SST. Unrecoverable.
130206 14:53:56 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Here's what Node 1 reports while Node 2 is connecting (Node 1 using the first config file - again trimmed)

```
130206 14:59:44 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out)
         at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():139
130206 14:59:44 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.c:gcs_core_open():195: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
130206 14:59:44 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.c:gcs_open():1290: Failed to open channel 'percona_cluster' at 'gcomm://192.168.2.11': -110 (Connection timed out)
130206 14:59:44 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
130206 14:59:44 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect() failed: 6
130206 14:59:44 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Node 2 reported similar.

If anyone can help me with what silly mistake I've made, it would be greatly appreciated.

*(Sorry for the length of the post - I wanted to provide as much info as possible)*

Comment: I'm Percona's online community manager, and while I am not personally technical enough to help with this particular issue, I just wanted to offer the option of posting this question on our XtraDB Cluster forum. Then if you get a solution you could share it here. http://www.perconaforum.com/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=13& On a related note, I'm new to Percona and am working to revamp the community -- so looking at ways of integrating feeds from Q&A sites like this into our own community in the future to provide multiple ways of solving issues and sharing that knowledge/best practices.
-Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there was something wrong with my install. Installing on clean servers setup went fine, but using it as a dropin replacement I ran into errors.

I needed to completely purge the other mysql software I had to get it to run better on my 'dirty' servers.

Comment: what d you mean? what you have done for resolving this issue?